# Open mobile app when you click a link in IOS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, devops, deep-linking

I am working on a React project. The same web app has its Android and IOS apps as well.
When I copy a web app's link to android users' mobile phone, It asked to open through web or app like this.

[image]

But I try to open the same thing with the IOS device. It directly opens the link in the web browser.

I am new to this project and I have no access to any documentation for the project. How can I add android behaviour to the IOS? Is this can be done in the React web app itself?

Comment: Please don't include notes like "thanks in advanced[sic]" in questions. See [no thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help with support universal links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

In addition, there is a very detailed explanation here in terms of react native. I wanted to direct you in case you might not have come across.

https://rossbulat.medium.com/deep-linking-in-react-native-with-universal-links-and-url-schemes-7bc116e8ea8b